# Why does $http.get not need to return anything?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angular-promise

I'm working on an angular app and I have a controller that is calling a service.  The controller sends a Url to the service.  The service sends a GET request to that Url and receives JSON back.  In that JSON is a Uri for Http requests.  I extract that Uri from the JSON and then redirect the browser to it.

The **JSON** returned from the endpoint looks like this

```
{  
   "profile":"...",
   "releases_url":"http://...",
   "name":"...",
   ...,
   "uri":"http://the-value-i-want-to-return.com",
   ...,
}
```

**Service Code**

```
// Resolves an API endpoint link to its Http counterpart
function resolveJSONEndpointToHttpUrl(JSONEndpointUrl) {
    return $http({ method: 'GET', url: JSONEndpointUrl }).
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("resolveJSONEndpointToHttpUrl : data");
            console.log(data);

            //return data;
        }).
        error(function (data, status, headers, config) {});
}
```

**Controller Code**

```
function redirectViaJSONLink(url) {
    return musicCollectionService.resolveJSONEndpointToHttpUrl(url).then(function (data) {
        console.log("redirectViaJSONLink : data");
        console.log(data);
        console.log("redirectViaJSONLink : data.data");
        console.log(data.data);
        console.log("redirectViaJSONLink : data.data.uri");
        console.log(data.data.uri);

        // Perform redirection
        // $window.location.href = data.uri;
    });
}
```

As you can see I'm doing some logging to break down the JSON and figure out exactly what is being returned to me and how to access the properties of the returned object.

My questions are:

1. Why do I not need to `return data;` in my `$http .success` call?  In what situations would I need to?
2. Is there a way to return a specific property from the data object in the `$http .success` call so that I don't have to call `data.data.uri` in my Controller method?  Or could I modify the returned JSON payload before it is returned to my Controller?

Comment: if you want to manipulate the data, do it in a `then` callback in service not in `success`. You can chain numerous `then` together

Comment: 1) You do something with the data not return it. 2) Can you not write a function that you can call from success to process the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `.success` or `.error` from a promise, Angular does nothing with the return value, so there is no point in returning anything. The value passed to the `.success/.error` callbacks is the result from the original promise.

If you use `.then(success,error)` however, then the return value is passed to the next promise in the promise chain.

For example, you could modify your service to use `.then` and return the uri:

**Service**

```
// Resolves an API endpoint link to its Http counterpart
function resolveJSONEndpointToHttpUrl(JSONEndpointUrl) {
    return $http({ method: 'GET', url: JSONEndpointUrl }).
        then(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("resolveJSONEndpointToHttpUrl : data");
            console.log(data);

            return data.data.uri;
        });
}
```

**Controller**

Then, in your controller, you can handle the result:

```
function redirectViaJSONLink(url) {
    return musicCollectionService.resolveJSONEndpointToHttpUrl(url).then(function (uri) {

        // Perform redirection
        $window.location.href = uri;
    });
}
```